# NextJS production build is huge

Tags: webpack, next.js

[My build screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0G6z.png)

For some reason the styles.js chunk is huge(300Kb), this happens even when I remove all the CSS files from the application.
FYI, I have used material-ui for develpment, I'm not sure if this should affect the First Load size. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: Dump your build cache folder `/.next` and try the build again.

Comment: Tried that just now, didn't change anything

Comment: I'd recommend running [`@next/bundle-analyzer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/bundle-analyzer) to pinpoint which dependencies are most contributing to that size. Then investigate if something can be done to reduce them on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: You can select certain packages from material-ui, you don't need to include the whole thing. Just do `@material-ui/what-you-need`